# Python: How do I make the index values in my "if statement" be the next one in order to loop through all the values of my list

Tags: python, list, indexing

I am trying to write a simple while loop that will tell me if a list follows a certain pattern. The code I have so far is this:

```
list = [4,8,12,16,20,24]
i = 0
while i < len(list):
        if list[1] - list[0] == list[2] - list[1]:
            i = i + 1
            list[0] = list[0 + 1]
            list[1] = list[1+1]
            list[2] = list[2 + 1]
            print ("true")
```

I'm trying to basically make the next loop say:

```
if list[2] - list[1] == list[3] - list[2]:
```

And so on until "i" is greater than the length of my list. What can I do?

Comment: Use `i`, `i+1`, and `i+2` inside your `if` condition.  Keep a boolean flag on whether everything so far is happy. Set it true before entering the loop. Only touch it if the condition fails, and test it after loop is done.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```py
lst = [4,8,12,16,20,24]
b = True
for i in range(len(lst)-2):
    b &= lst[i+2]-lst[i+1] == lst[i+1]-lst[i]
print(b) # Print "True" if follow the pattern else "False"
```

What does this program do?

It compares `lst[i+2]-lst[i+1]` and `lst[i+1]-lst[i]`.
If they are equals, `lst[i+2]-lst[i+1] == lst[i+1]-lst[i]` Will be `True`.

And what `&=` does:

If b is true and `lst[i+2]-lst[i+1] == lst[i+1]-lst[i]` true, b will be true, but if one of theme if false, it will be false.
So, at the end, for b to be True, the difference between `lst[i+2]-lst[i+1]` and `lst[i+1]-lst[i]` should be equal each time !

You can also have a different approach by defining the difference at the begging like that:

```py
lst = [4,8,12,16,20,24]
diff = lst[1] - lst[0] # 4
b = True
for i in range(len(lst)-2):
    b &= lst[i+2]-diff == lst[i+1]
print(b) # True
```

It's the same principle. You initialize the difference between the 2 first elements, then check if the difference is the same everywhere

Here is a more "advanced" tip if you want to solve it in a `golfy` way. You can use the `all` keyword to do it in oneline:

```py
lst = [4,8,12,16,20,24]
print(all(lst[i+2]-lst[i+1] == lst[i+1]-lst[i] for i in range(len(lst)-2))) # True
```

If you don't know how to use `all`:
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/all

Comment: Your answer could use an explanation of how/why it works. Code-only answers are discouraged here. Please [edit] it to include this information. Read [answer] to learn more about answering questions.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin Im doing it

Comment: Thank you @TKirishima! I have one more question, is the "-2" in the for statement there to balance out the "+2" under it so that the list does not try to reach indexes that are not there?

Comment: @Waev exact! If there wasnt any -2 it would create an IndexError

Comment: @Waev Don't hesitate to put this Question as Closed or to mark the Answer as correct